# Open GUI apps on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine via SSH from an Ubuntu 14.04 machine

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, ssh, gui

I'm trying to open GUI apps (gedit/nautilus/firefox) on a 16.04 machine via SSH from a 14.04 machine. The command I use is:

```
ssh -X username@ipaddress
```

and then, for example:

```
nautilus
```

However, it doesn't open the app and says

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It doesn't say anything else, just that. Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What other error messages do you see? There are a myriad reasons for a segfault.

Comment: Edit your question and provide every command related to your issue.

Comment: @edwinskl, there are no more error messages. Just the segfault. If you can tell me how to get a more verbose message, I can try that.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y libepoxy-dev`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. I ran `strace` with `meld` and `gedit` and it indicated that for some reason there was problem finding `libGLX_indirect.so.0` library. I attempted a fix by placing relevant symbolic link inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` folder:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX_indirect.so.0
```

and it works now. Would like to know what is the preferred way of fixing it.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was hard to find on google, thanks for the solution :-)

Comment: I had the same problem with i3wm. After an upgrade (probably nvidia drivers), gnome-terminal would no longer start. Dmesg showed a segfault  error 4 in libc-2.23.so. Adding the symlink for libGX_indirect resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: This solved a ton of issues I had with x2go and generally x-forwarding that I thought were policykit related on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. In some way, the policykit triggered auth dialog depended on this and then silently failed. It seems like quite a few programs had this dependency, e.g. firefox segfaulted as well without the symlink. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great this worked. Thanks.
PS: For my machine I had to do:
 sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX_indirect.so.0
due to different graphics driver versions.

Comment: With Bionic Beaver (18.04) there is a default symlink that needs to be overwritten. The command changes to `sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/nvidia-387/libGLX_indirect.so.0`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works, however according to [Launchpad Bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libepoxy/+bug/1574886), the real cause is [libepoxy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libepoxy/+bug/1574886/comments/8).  libepoxy has been fixed since early 2017, but as of June 2017, it is not available as an updated package for 16.04.  I followed the instructions by [Raj Bhattacharjea](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libepoxy/+bug/1574886/comments/13) to fix this issue. Specifically:

1. Downloaded the Zesty (17.04) libepoxy for my architecture from
   https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libs/libepoxy0 (for me it was
   [amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/libepoxy0/download)).
2. `sudo dpkg -i libepoxy0_1.3.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` (or your architecture version)

Problem solved. As much as I don't like using a package from another version, this seems like the cleaner solution, especially since I don't have to worry about my link breaking if I change NVidia versions.