# Xfce4 damaged after upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: xfce

After upgrade, every application from Xfce4 end like this:

```
[ 1065.315828] ibus-x11[16879]: segfault at 0 ip 00007feec2356b3f sp 00007ffde55973e8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7feec22c1000+1c0000] [
1065.315856] ibus-ui-gtk3[16875]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f0a13cc8b3f sp 00007ffc000bcae8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f0a13c33000+1c0000] [
1068.203949] nm-applet[16961]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f184a517b3f sp 00007fff6eb1a3a8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f184a482000+1c0000] [
1068.266182] light-locker[16973]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fcf873bbb3f sp 00007ffdc7781798 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fcf87326000+1c0000] [
1068.592575] nvidia-settings[16983]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f8d84ecfb3f sp 00007ffefef07f18 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f8d84e3a000+1c0000] [
1068.840970] polkit-gnome-au[17076]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f4c102c1b3f sp 00007ffd1cff8478 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f4c1022c000+1c0000] [
1068.930742] update-notifier[17089]: segfault at 0 ip 00007ff4a99f5b3f sp 00007ffc9e8d79c8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7ff4a9960000+1c0000] [
1069.088903] notify-osd[17101]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f4c7c238b3f sp 00007fff2373b7b8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f4c7c1a3000+1c0000] [
1069.618902] blueman-applet[17052]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f1aaf9d9b3f sp 00007fffe1732678 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f1aaf944000+1c0000] [
1069.719267] evolution-alarm[16953]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f725949cb3f sp 00007ffef9a3b568 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f7259407000+1c0000] [
1078.931214] virt-manager[17238]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f4d1c4a0b3f sp 00007ffe3e4f0c18 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f4d1c40b000+1c0000]
```

Any solutions?

Comment: solutuion is here http://askubuntu.com/questions/795418/open-gui-apps-on-a-ubuntu-16-04-machine-via-ssh-from-an-ubuntu-14-04-machine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can use the Ubuntu Live-Dvd/Usb  to run apt-get to get the new files to fix your system:

```
Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
Run in the terminal:

sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

The output of `fdisk -l` like as this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0008a792

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 102402047 102195200  48.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       102402048 307202047 204800000  97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       307204094 614682623 307478530 146.6G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       307204096 409604095 102400000  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       409606144 585385983 175779840  83.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       585388032 614682623  29294592    14G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Continue running:

```
umount /dev/sda6
fsck -a /dev/sda6
mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the open file add OpenDNS name servers, type this lines:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Save file: Control + O -- Close nano: Control + X, continue running

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
exit
reboot
```

If an application stops the process by an error, repeat the command. If error persists, remove it: `apt-get remove [app]`

Comment: Thanx for help. I have access to command line and system is bootable so above steps afaik are not needed  but dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update   
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove 
apt-get clean
exit
reboot   does noit help. is it possible to have some old libc stuck somewhere ?