# Problems over xrdp, vnc and x2go

Tags: nvidia, graphics, x2go

I'm having issues running several applications when connected to my ubuntu desktop remotely.  I think it may be related to the graphics card (nvidia m2000) and could use some help figuring out what to try to fix it.  I had to install a couple of different nvidia drivers to get my machine to boot with dual monitors, and settled on this driver which seems to allow my system to boot locally without issue.  The following were done over x2go, although others are similar.

nvidia-xconfig:

```
$ nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info
Number of GPUs: 1

GPU #0:
    Name      : Quadro M2000
    UUID      : GPU-c27f7ac6-a9b8-090a-e47c-f00d408fae68
    PCI BusID : PCI:2:0:0

    Number of Display Devices: 2

    Display Device 0 (TV-5):
        EDID Name             : LG Electronics 27MP35
        Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
        Maximum HorizSync     : 83.000 kHz
        Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
        Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
        Maximum PixelClock    : 150.000 MHz
        Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
        Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
        Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
        Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
        Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
        Physical Width        : 600 mm
        Physical Height       : 340 mm

    Display Device 1 (TV-7):
        EDID Name             : LG Electronics 27MP35
        Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
        Maximum HorizSync     : 83.000 kHz
        Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
        Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
        Maximum PixelClock    : 150.000 MHz
        Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
        Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
        Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
        Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
        Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
        Physical Width        : 600 mm
        Physical Height       : 340 mm
```

lspci:

```
$lspci
...
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1430 (rev a1)
...
```

lshw:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:53 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:fb000000-fb07ffff
```

monitors:

```
$ egrep -i " connected|card detect|primary dev|Setting driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    16.376] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics 27MP35 (DFP-5): connected
[    16.439] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics 27MP35 (DFP-7): connected
```

Some examples of the issues I'm seeing:

```
$nvidia-settings
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ firefox
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 31118
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ time-admin
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ google-chrome
[1164:1164:0207/011022.111253:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(411)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[1164:1164:0207/011022.111309:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(130)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[1164:1164:0207/011022.112741:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(327)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[1089:1121:0207/011022.309812:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(113)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[1089:1121:0207/011022.311129:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(113)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[1089:1121:0207/011022.312792:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(113)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[1089:1121:0207/011022.313561:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(113)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[1089:1121:0207/011022.318306:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(113)] Failed to launch GPU process
```

A note on the GLX error message, here's a bit of info from glxinfo, which shows the version is 1.4:

```
$ glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 378.09
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 378.09
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 378.09
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions,
```

What do i need to change in order to make my applications usable remotely?

Comment: 100+ views and 0 responses.  I must be posting in the wrong place.  Where else can I try?

Comment: I had the same problem, it seemed to occur every now and then following updates related to the nvidia driver. This solution worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/796159/593727 I needed to find the library in the folder .../nvidia-375/.